# Bundler is not "bundling" sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, bundler, dreamhost

I have a very recurrent problem here. (it happens literally all the time). I have found ways to go around it but i really would appreciate a solution for this problem:

Here is how it goes:

At my development machine, i have in my gem file a line like this:

```
gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3"
```

what happens is that, when i bundle install --no-deployment, it goes alright:

```
Using sqlite3 (1.3.5)
Using sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
Updating .gem files in vendor/cache
Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
```

But then, in the deployment, running bundle install --deployment, i get:

```
Using sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
Updating .gem files in vendor/cache
Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
```

... which causes require errors that makes the application crash.. Then, what i do is bundle install --no-deployment at the deployment machine. Then i run again bundle install --deployment and then, magically:

```
Using sqlite3 (1.3.5)
Using sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
Updating .gem files in vendor/cache
```

And then the application runs fine.

So, what i most basically want is that bundler recognizes the sqlite3 dependency on sqlite3 gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But then, in the development, running bundle install --deployment, i get:

Okay, this is the first suspicious thing. Why would you run `--deployment` in development?

You generally don't want to do that. If you're switching all the time between "--deployment" and "--no-deployment" on the same machine, it's easy to get things confused, yes.

Running "bundle install --deployment" will save something in the `.bundle/config` file in your project, that tells bundler "from here on out, only install these certain gems".  "--no-deployment" removes that again, in case you made a mistake or need to hack around. But in general, you shouldn't need to and don't want to always be switching back and forth. Run `--deployment` on your production/deployment machine, don't run it on your development machine. You don't ever need to run `--no-deployment` unless you made a mistake and didn't mean `--deployment`

At this point, I'd `rm -rf .bundle` (it's okay, it'll just remove all the things bundler 'remembers' about what you want to do, like `--deployment`), and start over with `bundle install`.

If there's some reason this doesn't work, then that's the question.

From the line `Updating .gem files in vendor/cache`, I suspect at some point you also ran `bundle package`, which is another thing that's "remembered" in the `.bundle/config` thing, and is also probably interacting with your other commands oddly and doing things you don't expect.  Removing your `.bundle/config` will get rid of that remembered setting too. (you may also need to delete your ./vendor/cache directory contents)

Just run `bundle install` unless you have a reason you understand for needing `package`, and understand what it does.  Or it'll confuse you.

Comment: I meant deployment, not development. Nevertheless, your answer clarified me some stuff. I'll deploy a new website soon then i'll let you know the results. Thanks anyway for your explanations.